# Lost Wi-Fi passwords after reset network settings on iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, wifi, password, keychain

After a network configuration reset on my iPhone all Wi-Fi passwords were lost. They were stored in iCloud Keychain, synced with my Mac, where they disappeared too. This is very frustrating since it seems that they were store only on iCloud and I can't restore them via old Time Machine backups.
(In Keychain on my Mac I have only some of them, 90% are lost.)

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to access this information. The passwords are kept on your phone in a safe place that is not accessible through any regular means on the phone. This is done for your protection, if you were to lose your iPhone and someone picked it up, the passwords that are stored on it would be up for grabs. This would lead to a lot of security problems.

So hereafter I would recommend to use certain apps like 1password to keep your passwords safe and backed up..

Comment: Same happened here. I thought all password were stored on the iCloud keychain. Could we not rsync them from that?

Comment: Yes, I called Tim Cook. He said it’s a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this question and this was suggested by someone on a forum:

1. Disable iCloud Keychain from the iCloud settings page (On the top of settings if running iOS 10.3, down the list if running other versions of iOS)
2. Do the "Reset network settings" to debug the network issue you're experiencing
3. All the Wi-Fi passwords should now be deleted. What you now have to do is to connect to a network manually, then re enabling your iCloud Keychain, your old WiFi passwords should have resynced and you should now have access to all previously connected WiFis.

Note that I haven't tested this personally, but I just came across this because I'm trying to debug a problem when my iPad disconnects from WiFi only when streaming Netflix.

Comment: I followed this and it worked as expected -- just disable iCloud Keychain before clearing network settings then re-enable afterwards, my Wi-Fi passwords were re-synced to my phone over LTE (as evidenced by not having to put in my password to connect to my WiFi network).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an Airport base? If so, you can force the password to be added back to your keychain from there (assuming it is in the airport base settings).

Go to Airport Utility/Edit/Wireless
in this tab the name of your WiFi should be mentioned, with the password typed but not visible. If not selected yet, then tick the box for "Remember this password in may keychain", then it should save an item in you keychain again and your mac reconnecting automatically to this WiFi

Good luck