# How can I prevent "Reset network settings" on my iPhone from affecting my Laptop?

Tags: iphone, network, icloud, wifi, password

I just hit reset network settings on my iPhone (9.2.1) because I was unable to make phone calls.

I then noticed that my OSX (10.11.3) lost its internet connection.  I immediately checked the keychain (where all wifi passwords are stored) and noticed that all passwords are missing.

I can only assume that resetting the iPhone "network settings" also affected my mac.  I assume this occurred through iCloud.

**Question**

- How can I get those Wifi Passwords back?
- How can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: I feel your pain :( I lost some of my passwords to a very bad system crash a while ago. Since then I have been keeping a backup of my passwords in a text file on an encrypted drive.

Comment: I might have the answer to your second question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283657/1898

Answer (score 1):

Check to seen if your passwords still exist under `Safari > Preferences > Passwords` on your Mac. Maybe they are still there.

If this doesn't work, try the following: Unplug your router's ethernet cable (so that iCloud cannot sync with the server) and try to restore your from Time Machine. This should revert your Key Chain. I recommend disconnecting your router because if you just turn off your wifi, it will probably turn back on after the restore is done and sync with iCloud again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to prevent it from happening, but I fixed it last time by getting a copy of my keychain via TimeMachine and reimporting them.